# Php array_diff() issue

Tags: php

I have seen some similar issues here but could not get an answer to my problem.

I am using the array_diff function to take the difference of two arrays, but it does not work. Here is my code.

```
$remainings = array_diff($quals,$assigned);
for($i=0;$i<count($quals);$i++)
  echo $quals[$i].'-';
echo count($quals);
echo "<br>";
for($i=0;$i<count($assigned);$i++)
  echo $assigned[$i].'-';
echo count($assigned);  
echo "<br>";  
for($i=0;$i<count($remainings);$i++)
  echo $remainings[$i].'-';
echo count($remainings);
```

This is what I get as the output:

TeamA-TeamB-TeamC-TeamD-TeamE-TeamF-TeamG-TeamH-TeamI-TeamJ-TeamK-TeamL-12

--TeamE-TeamF---TeamD-TeamH----TeamG-12

TeamA-TeamB-TeamC-----7

What I would expect in the last line is:

TeamA-TeamB-TeamC-TeamI-TeamJ-TeamK-TeamL-7

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is shown in the output. Quals has Teams from A to L. Assigned has Team E, F, D, H, G

Comment: Its a good idea to make it ez for people to help you. they should be able to copy paste the code, and run it. The preparation is your job.

Comment: I understand. I am populating those arrays in a totally different place. So copy pasting that code wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: so hardcode it? you'll probably discover your mistake in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting those because array_diff retains the original keys from the first array

so your `$remainings` array looks like this

```
Array ( 
   [0] => TeamA 
   [1] => TeamB 
   [2] => TeamC 
   [8] => TeamI 
   [9] => TeamJ 
   [10] => TeamK 
   [11] => TeamL 
)
```

Notice the 8,9,10,11 indexes for the last half of the team names

so when you were doing the for loop you had the index going from 0 to 7, and since there is no 3,4,5,6 indexes nothing was being printed (you would have gotten an E_NOTICE undefined index error if you had display_errors on)

so instead of doing the regular for loop use a foreach loop

```
foreach($remainings as $team)
  echo $team.'-';
echo count($remainings);
```

will output:
`TeamA-TeamB-TeamC-TeamI-TeamJ-TeamK-TeamL-7`

[***PHPFiddle*** Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/03s-pnv) (hit the run button)

As Niet the Dark Absol mentions you can also just use `array_values` to "reset" the keys 
just do the following:

```
$remainings = array_values( array_diff($quals,$assigned) );
```

> ***http://php.net/array-values***
>
> array_values() returns all the values from
>   the array and indexes the array numerically.

Comment: You can also use `array_values` to "reset" the keys.